# Tab bar item not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

```
    if(!isUserLoggedIn){

        var loginViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginView") as! LoginViewController

        window!.rootViewController = loginViewController
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }else{

        var mainViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainView") as! FirstViewController         
        var myDealsViewController  = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myDealsViewController") as!MyDealsViewController            
        var settingsViewController  = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("settingsView") as! SettingsViewController            
        var centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController) as UINavigationController
        var myDealNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myDealsViewController) as UINavigationController            
        let controllers = [centerNav,myDealNavController,settingsViewController]
        tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers

        window!.rootViewController = tabBarController
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()          
    }
```

the above code is working but the app is not showing the tab bar item even though it works when I click on the center tab bar item.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you setup the tab bar item? In storyboard or in some other part of the code?

Comment: On the storyboard only

Comment: As seeing image of your storyboard, there are only two controllers you set up with tabbar controller and programatically you have add three controllers. Where is the third one in storyboard...? Add third controller and connect with tabbar and try.

Comment: There is another controller (home) which is not shown I'm the picture

Comment: I think you should just setup the tabbaritem for each of the navbarcontrollers that you are creating in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace line of your code with :

```
var myDealNavController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myDealNavController") as! UINavigationController
```

And set "myDealNavController" as identifier to your UINavigationController  in storyboard.